# Can't connect navicat to mysql

Tags: mysql, navicat

I have FreeBSD with mysql server and want to connect navicat with them. On vBox I have bridged network (192.168.0.225). I can ping to this from my system (192.168.0.135)

With ssh and ftp, it isn't a problem.

> navicat error: 2003 -can't connnect to mysql server on 192.168.0.225.
>   10061 unknown error

Answer (score 1):

It's a navicat's bug.
Delete the connection config where in navicat/servers/your-connection-name. 
Then try to create a new connection and run.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely, your `mysqld` is only listening on the local socket (`/tmp/mysql.sock` or some such). That's the most secure mode.

To make it more promiscuous, you'll need to configure the server to listen for TCP-connections as well.

Look for the `bind-address` setting in the `[mysqld]` section of `/usr/local/mysql/my.cnf`. You'll, probably, need something like

```
bind-address = 192.168.0.225
```

Consult [this tutorial](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/remote-access/) for more information on how to then authorize remote users -- MySQL allows configuring different passwords and access-policies depending on the where the connection is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably disabled all apps from the service.

1. Click from start menu System Configuration
2. Click Services
3. Hide all Microsoft Services
4. Click following picture,which you install DB then enable and apply.[image]